# Handling Dictionary values incase if it is null

Tags: c#, linq

I have two dictionaries

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

The requirement is to get all the values from `dictionary1`  and uncommon from `dictionary2`, which anyways I have implemented.

**The only issue is if anyone of the dictionaries is null I am getting an exception, I want to handle this null scenario. If any of the dictionaries is null then return the other dictionary.**

```cs
var demo = dictionary1
    .Concat(dictionary2
        .Where(kvp => !dictionary1.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
    )
    .ToList();
```

Can someone please guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean Dictionary is empty or null, you can always put a null check before doing this concat?

Comment: Just as Pankaj mentioned, a null check should work, like: var demo = dictionary1 != null && dictionary2 != null ? dictionary1 .Concat(dictionary2 .Where(kvp => !dictionary1 .ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToList() : dictionary1 == null ? dictionary2 : dictionary1;

Comment: How can the dictionaries be null when you assign a value to the variables when you define them? Are you setting the variables to `null` at any point? What is the actual, full exception text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Concat` is a not a good idea, since the main advantage of a dictionary, i.e., a [constant lookup time](http://net-informations.com/faq/general/dictionary-list.htm), gets lost!

Use the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator instead:

```cs
if ((dictionary1 ?? dictionary2).TryGetValue(key, out string value)) {
    ...
}
```

If both dictionaries can be `null`, you can add a third term:

```cs
dictionary1 ?? dictionary2 ?? new Dictionary<string, string>()
```

or create an empty dictionary that you can reuse in this situation:

```cs
static readonly Dictionary<string, string> emptyDict = new();

...

if ((dictionary1 ?? dictionary2 ?? emptyDict).TryGetValue(key, out string value)) {
    ...
}
```

Null-coalescing operator chains  `a ?? b ?? c ?? d` return the first non-null value if any and otherwise `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if dictionary is `null` (and create empty one) before query:

```
dictionary1 ??= new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary2 ??= new Dictionary<string, string>();

// no changes
var demo = dictionary1.Concat(dictionary2.Where(kvp => !dictionary1.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToList();
```

Comment: The dictionaries in the question's code can never be null unless the OP explicitly sets them to null after defining them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, but I think dictionaries in question are just shown as an example. In other case there wouldn't be such question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `null` instead of empty collection is often a bad practice, however if you have to work with `null` dictionaries
you can use `?.` instead of just `.`

```
// let's return empty list (not null) if any of dictionary is null
// if you want to have demo being null, remove ?? ... fragment
var demo = dictionary1
  ?.Concat(dictionary2
              ?.Where(kvp => dictionary1
              ?.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) == false))
  ?.ToList() ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

the only small difficulty is with `?.ContainsKey(...)`: it returns `bool?` instead of `bool` that's why we can't put `!` but have to compare with `false` or `true`.